# jQuery regex selector

Tags: jquery, regex

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tree div').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.tree div:regex(id,^['+id+'_])').html('this one');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="tree">
    <div id="item_1">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'ketab')); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate("Add Ketab"); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="item_1_1">
        <span></span>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'ketab')); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate("Add Ketab"); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div id="item_1_2">
        <span></span>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'ketab')); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate("Add Ketab"); ?></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want hide `item_1_1` and `item_1_2` when i click on `item_1`, I don't know how can i do that with regex.

I use http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ for regx

Comment: Interesting hack to post the HTML ;-) You don't actually need to escape all your HTML and use `<pre><code>` tags though. Just paste your original HTML and press the `{}` code button. For newlines, rather than using `<br/>`, just press enter twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the regex selector here. Use jQuery's built-in [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('#item_1').click(function () {
    $('[id^="item_1"]').hide();
});
```

If you just want to use that plugin anyway, then your selector would be:

```
':regex(id, ^item_1)'
```

Comment: Good advice there. The jQuery starts with selector would be a much quicker method than using the :regex selector plugin, which is very slow.

Comment: how about when I have children for item_1_2 ?

Comment: @Mohammad the children will get hidden as well.

Answer (score 0):

no need regex

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tree div').click(function(){

    $('.tree div').hide();
    $(this).show()

    });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with your naming schema or you could just simply...

```
$("div > div a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

Hide the div siblings of the clicked link within the div, especially if you're building this as a tree structure... [See the fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/veCqr/). This would actually apply to all links inside divs that are children of other divs, so you could restrict this by performing a $("div.tree").find("div > div") selection and binding the event to that set to make children divs behave the same.

Alternatively, if you just want to see something fun that may be along the lines of what you're attempting to do, [here's a fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/PgwRd/) while messing around with tree style navigation. It might lead you to consider other approaches, especially since I'm not sure your code has taken into consideration the matter of displaying those divs again in the event that wasn't what the user really wanted.